# It freezing on starting screen while installing or trying Ubuntu (dual - boot)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, freeze

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.02 alongside Windows 10. I shrinked the space, writed the ubuntu.iso on usb with rufus ( i tried alternative tools also) and reboot the computer. When I select the Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu option 
[it freezing this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shiIJ.png)

It fills and refills once and stays.

How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

my system:

i7 6700hq 2.6 mhz
nvidia gtx950m
20gb 2133 mhz ddr4 ram

Comment: First you need to read and understand this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Then, at the Grub menu with the "Try Ubuntu..." option selected, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the entry and add `nomodeset` after or instead of `quiet splash`. This parameter gives you low res video, enough to install. Repeat the editing after installing Ubuntu, install all updates and then search for "Additional drivers" in the dash and select & apply the recommended Nvidia drivers for your card. Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried adding "nomodeset" but it asked me password. I entered id:ubuntu and password: - blank - and then it did nothing. What I write then?
My PC has legacy BIOS. I bought it as freedos and firstly I installed Windows 10.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again. It shouldn't ask for password.

Comment: Secure boot is already disabled but result is the same.

Comment: You're doing something (really) wrong then. Editing a Grub parameter does not and cannot ask for password. Please get back to the UEFI link above, read it and understand it, and assure you're booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: I dont want to boot UEFI mode because my PC has BIOS and I can pass the password entering id ubuntu. Even so I am reading link above. Hopefully it wiil resolve the problem

Comment: Booting in legacy (refer to the UEFI link again) shows a different menu. Just press F6 and select nomodeset. Your PC most likely has UEFI but of course "FreeDOS" requires legacy mode. Now, installing Windows 10 in Legacy as well was your first mistake, really not smart (this is what I can post, not exactly what I'm thinking).

Comment: You either reinstall Windows 10 in UEFI mode and then do the same for Ubuntu -or- keep it like this and boot and install Ubuntu in Legacy mode. Either way you **may** need the nomodeset parameter and I already explained how to use it in both modes. I'm sorry, there's really no other way to explain this quite simple concepts. If the language is a problem then you should use help resources in your native language (local Ubuntu forum, etc.). This is a Q&A, not a forum, and comments are for clarification, not for extended discussion.